# Not able to run JFlex generated lexer Java file

Tags: java, compiler-construction, lex, lexer, jflex

So I used JFlex to generate a file called Yylex.java without any problems. When I try to compile it with the command `javac Yylex.java`, I get 30 errors, originating with this one:

```
Yylex.java:13: error: package java_cup.runtime does not exist
import java_cup.runtime.Symbol;
```

This is obviously caused by the first import in my JFlex file. Since I'm trying to use this with CUP, I read that I need to have the java-cup-11a.jar file and the java-cup-11a-runtime.jar in the same folder as Yylex.java, which I do. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply putting the jars in the dir is not enough, you have to add them to the classpath using the `-cp` command line option, so e.g.

`javac -cp ava-cup-11a-runtime.jar Yylex.java`

Comment: Suppose I have a bunch of other java files I need to add to the classpath as well. Is there anyway to permanently add them, instead of typing them all in everytime?

Comment: You can set the CLASSPATH environment variable. But if your project is getting bigger, you're better of using a build tool such as ant or maven to manage these things, or use an IDE like eclipse. They're all free to download.